# Apagando OBJECT_TYPE do Oracle

Tags: oracle

Boa tarde.

Como que eu faço para pagar um OBJECT_TYPE do meu OWNER?
preciso apagar esse object_type, pos ele está dando erro de SYNON

Comment: Poderia fornecer mais informações? Colocar o script que está dando erro? Acredito que a solução não seja deletar um `object_type`.

Comment: Quando eu faço um create table, ele da erro dizendo que ja possui em alguma tabela esse nome, mas na verdade não tem (ja fiz o teste).
Então ele da erro e SYNONYM, que esse eu sei que tem.

Estou tentando executar esse script mas não estou conseguindo



DROP TYPE = 'SYNONYM'
WHERE OWNER = 'SYSFOL'

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode ter um `SYNONYM` e um outro `TYPE` com o mesmo nome. `SYNONYM` é um `TYPE`, assim como `TABLE`,`PROCEDURE`,`FUNCTION`, etc.

Pelo que eu entendi, você teria algumas opções:

1. Remove o `SYNONYM`. (caso não estiver utilizando)
2. Cria a tabela com outro nome. (caso seja possível)
3. Remove o `SYNONYM` e cria ele com outro nome, e assim cria a tabela com o nome.

---

Edit:
Para remover um `SYNONYM`, basta utilizar o comando:

```
DROP SYNONYN nome;
```

<sup>*Fonte: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9002.htm*</sup>

Comment: Eu quero remover o SYNONYM para criar uma tabela
Sabe como eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Adicionei a resposta, veja se te atende.

Comment: Consegui com esse script
drop public synonym e_movamap;

Comment: poderia marcar a pergunta como respondida ? Na dúvida, visite o [tour]